# In a table of multiple invoices per client, I want to identify the first invoice (row) for each client

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have tried this but it does not produce what I expect:

```
SELECT 
       client_id,
       invoice_date,
       invoice_number,
       invoice_value
FROM tblInvoices
WHERE tblInvoices.invoice_date IN
    (SELECT min(tblInvoices.invoice_date)
     FROM tblInvoices
     GROUP BY client_id)
GROUP BY client_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery gets minimal invoice_date for each separate client, but the link between the client and his date is lost.

```
SELECT client_id,
       invoice_date,
       invoice_number,
       invoice_value
FROM tblInvoices
WHERE (client_id, invoice_date) IN ( SELECT client_id, min(invoice_date)
                                     FROM tblInvoices
                                     GROUP BY client_id )
```

If there exists more than one record for some client with the same minimal date - all of them will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a correlated subquery to filter the table:

```
select t.*
from tblinvoices t
where t.invoice_date = (
    select min(t1.invoice_date) 
    from tblinvoices t1 
    where t1.client_id = t.client_id
)
```

This option generally produces good performance with the right index in place - here, you want an index on `(client_id, invoice_date)`.

Another typical solution is the anti-left join:

```
select t.*
from tblinvoices t
left join tblinvoices t1 
    on  t1.client_id = t.client_id
    and t1.invoice_date < t.invoice_date
where t1.client_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get clients and its data by checking invoice_date against its minimum value for each user using a subquery join.

```
SELECT client_id,
       invoice_date,
       invoice_number,
       invoice_value
FROM tblInvoices AS upper_table
WHERE invoice_date IN (
                        SELECT min(invoice_date)
                        FROM tblInvoices
                        WHERE upper_table.client_id=tblInvoices.client_id
                      )
```

Comment: MySQL implements DISTINCT over the whole record only. That's not postgresql which allows DISTINCT the output over partial fieldset.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, you are right. We could get the same result without adding `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem with multiple solutions. This one uses an uncorrelated subquery with an inner join:

```
SELECT 
    t.client_id,
    invoice_date,
    invoice_number,
    invoice_value
FROM tblInvoices t
JOIN (
    SELECT client_id, MIN(invoice_date) AS min_invoice_date
    FROM tblInvoices
    GROUP BY client_id
) sq ON t.client_id = sq.client_id AND t.invoice_date = sq.min_invoice_date
```

But what if the minimum invoice date were not unique for a given client (column `invoice_date` might be of type `DATE`; this was not specified)? Then the above SQL would return multiple rows for that client. Then we would want to return perhaps the row with the minimum invoice date and the minimum invoice number:

```
SELECT 
    t.client_id,
    invoice_date,
    invoice_number,
    invoice_value
FROM tblInvoices t
JOIN (
    SELECT t.client_id, MIN(invoice_number) AS min_invoice_number from tblInvoices t JOIN (
       SELECT client_id, MIN(invoice_date) AS min_invoice_date
       FROM tblInvoices
       GROUP BY client_id
    ) sq ON t.client_id = sq.client_id AND t.invoice_date = sq.min_invoice_date
    GROUP BY t.client_id
) sq2 ON /* t.client_id = sq2.client_id AND */ t.invoice_number = sq2.min_invoice_number
```

I am assuming in the above SQL that the `invoice_number` column is a unique key.